# What is the decomposition of potassium nitrite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, decomposition

I can find plenty of information on the decomposition of potassium nitrate into potassium nitrite and free oxygen, but apparently the resulting potassium nitrite likes to further decompose and produce even more free oxygen.  I cannot however find the reaction for this, and its products.  Do any of you know?

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{4 KNO2 -> 2 K2O + 2 N2 + 3 O2}$

Temperature is too high for $\ce{K2O2}$ or $\ce{KO2}$

Comment: You may want to cite this article. It mentioned the exact temperature: 800 C. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01561a015